# ldapjs handling client.search response

Tags: ldapjs

I have the below code which is binding to an LDAP server and I want to return the user that I have added "ab" within the "interviewees" group (code taken from ldapjs client api page). I can see I am getting back a response from the server with the expected EventEmitter object. I am expecting to see information about the user when calling logging console.log() on the searchEntry object. I appear to have no searchEntry objects. Is my DN for my user correct? I am currently unsure whether the issue is with my query and I am not getting any data back or whether I am failing to process the response correctly?

```
    const client = ldap.createClient({ url: 'ldap://' + LDAP_SERVER + ':' + LDAP_PORT });
    
    // Connect and bind to the Active Directory.
    const connectToClient = async () => {
      const secret = LDAP_SECRET_KEY;
      return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.bind(LDAP_USER, secret, function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            reject('Failed to connect to LDAP server');
          } else {
            resolve('Connected to LDAP server');
          }
        });
      });
    };
    
    onst searchADForUser = async () => {
      return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.search('CN=ab,OU=interviewees,OU=Users,OU=interview,DC=interview,DC=workspace,DC=com', function (err, res) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            reject('Error searching LDAP server');
          } else {
            res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
              console.log('entry: ' + JSON.stringify(entry.object));
            });
            res.on('searchReference', function (referral) {
              console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
            });
            res.on('error', function (err) {
              console.error('error: ' + err.message);
            });
            res.on('end', function (result) {
              console.log('status: ' + result.status);
            });
            resolve(res);
          }
        });
      });
    };
    
    const handler = async (event) => {
      try {
        return responses.success(
          await connectToClient().then(async function(event) {
            console.log(event);
            await searchADForUser().then(function(event) {
              console.log(event);
            }).catch(function(event) {
              console.log(event);
            })
          }).catch(function(event) {
            console.log(event);
          })
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return responses.error(err);
      } finally {
        client.unbind();
      }
    };
```

The active directory structure is below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The central issue I was having was understanding how to process the returned EventEmitter object from the search function. I need to add to an array on each *searchEntry* event and then return that entry in my *resolve* callback function only once the *end* event had occurred. The code above was calling resolve immediately and hence no *searchEntry* events or the *end* event had been processed yet.

Code I am now using below:

```
function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          reject(new Error('Error retrieving users from Active Directory'));
        } else {
          const entries = [];
          res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
            entries.push(entry);
          });
          res.on('searchReference', function (referral) {
            console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
          });
          res.on('error', function (err) {
            console.error('error: ' + err.message);
          });
          res.on('end', function (result) {
            console.log('status: ' + result.status);
            if (result.status !== 0) {
              reject(new Error('Error code received from Active Directory'));
            } else {
              resolve(entries);
            }
          });
        }
      }
```